# httpd-2.4.9 rpm build error File not found mod_session_crypto.so,mod_mpm_event.so

Tags: centos, rpmbuild

I am trying to build an RPM for `httpd-2.4.9` in CentOS 6 final 64 bit using command
  `-tb httpd-2.4.x.tar.bz2`. But I am getting following file not found error:

```
 RPM build errors:
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.9-1.x86_64/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.9-1.x86_64/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_session_crypto.so
```

Can any one help me sort out this issue?

Comment: I am having the same problem, if I figure it out I will let you know. I'm assuming it has something to do with the spec file, I'm not getting the error on crypto, which I'm trying to enable as well, but I am on the mod_mpm_event.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by installing the latest APR and APR Utility (http://apr.apache.org/) from source instead of pulling from yum and then installing httpd.

You may also need to change a line in the .spec file for the APR Utility if the crypto library will not install. The blog post at http://ramblin-dude.blogspot.com/2013/04/compiling-rpm-for-httpd-on-rhel-57.html explains that you need to change the line that reads `make check || exit 1` to `make check || continue` for it to compile correctly. I'm not sure if this is relevant in CentOS 6 but in my system with CentOS 5 I had to do this.