# httpd-2.4.18 CentOS 7 RPM build file not found: mod_mpm_event.so

Tags: apache, centos7, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build an RPM for `httpd-2.4.18` on CentOS 7.2.1511 (Core) using `rpmbuild -tb ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/httpd-2.4.18.tar.bz2`.  However, I keep getting the following error:

```
error: File not found: /home/administrator/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.18-1.x86_64/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
Executing(%doc): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.HmrPlX
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/administrator/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd httpd-2.4.18
+ DOCDIR=/home/administrator/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.18-1.x86_64/usr/share/doc/httpd-2.4.18
+ export DOCDIR
+ /usr/bin/mkdir -p /home/administrator/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.18-1.x86_64/usr/share/doc/httpd-2.4.18
+ cp -pr ABOUT_APACHE /home/administrator/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.18-1.x86_64/usr/share/doc/httpd-2.4.18
+ cp -pr README /home/administrator/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.18-1.x86_64/usr/share/doc/httpd-2.4.18
+ cp -pr CHANGES /home/administrator/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.18-1.x86_64/usr/share/doc/httpd-2.4.18
+ cp -pr LICENSE /home/administrator/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.18-1.x86_64/usr/share/doc/httpd-2.4.18
+ cp -pr NOTICE /home/administrator/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.18-1.x86_64/usr/share/doc/httpd-2.4.18
+ exit 0


RPM build errors:
    File not found: /home/administrator/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/httpd-2.4.18-1.x86_64/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892997/httpd-2-4-9-rpm-build-error-file-not-found-mod-session-crypto-so-mod-mpm-event-s) the problem is to do with the `apr` version.  From an earlier build failure due to lack of dependencies, the minimum `apr` versions are:

```
error: Failed build dependencies:
    apr-devel >= 1.4.0 is needed by httpd-2.4.18-1.x86_64
    apr-util-devel >= 1.4.0 is needed by httpd-2.4.18-1.x86_64
```

I have the following versions installed:

```
yum info apr-devel | grep Version
Version     : 1.4.8

yum info apr-util-devel | grep Version
Version     : 1.5.2
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question; however I will note that you should *never* build RPMs as the `root` user. A poorly (or maliciously) written `.spec` file can *easily* nuke your system.

Comment: Even if I'm not using `sudo` at the time?

Answer (score 0):

So I guess a mismatch in apr-devel and apr-util-devel packages is the cause of the problem.  Building an apr-1.5.2 RPM from source and upgrading the version that CentOS has fixed this issue.

Next question, which is more of me musing really, is whether this is the case for all packages that depend on apr and apr-util?  If so, why does the official CentOS repo have a different version for each?